# how to split column into multiple values using another

Tags: mysql, split

I have the following table:
date, hour, accidents

I have to get the number of accidents at night and day.

Here's how to get it in a day

> SELECT date, SUM(accidents) AS 'at day' FROM vehicles WHERE DATE>='2012-01-01 'AND DATE<='2012-01-31' AND HOUR>='00: 00:00' AND HOUR<=' 11:59:59 'GRUUP BY date

How do I modify the query to also have accidents at night?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adlibing here, but;

```
SELECT date,SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR>='00: 00:00' AND HOUR<=' 11:59:59
THEN accidents ELSE 0 END)
AS 'at day',
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR>='12: 00:00' AND HOUR<=' 23:59:59
THEN accidents ELSE 0 END) AS 'at night' 
FROM vehicles 
WHERE DATE>='2012-01-01 'AND DATE<='2012-01-31'
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `union`

```
SELECT date, SUM(accidents) AS 'at day', '' as 'at night'
FROM vehicles 
WHERE DATE>='2012-01-01 ' AND DATE<='2012-01-31' 
AND HOUR>='00: 00:00' AND HOUR<=' 11:59:59 '
GROUP BY date
union
SELECT date, '', as 'at day', SUM(accidents) AS 'at night' 
FROM vehicles 
WHERE DATE>='2012-01-01 ' AND DATE<='2012-01-31' 
AND HOUR>='12: 00:00' AND HOUR<=' 23:59:59 '
GROUP BY date
```

or use a `case`:

```
SELECT date, '', as 'at day', 
       SUM(accidents) AS 'sum_accidents', 
       case `HOUR` between '00: 00:00' and '11:59:59' THEN 'night' ELSE 'day' END as 'night_or_day'
FROM vehicles 
WHERE DATE>='2012-01-01 ' AND DATE<='2012-01-31' 
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, it works! (first solution) but how can i get off this empty space in first rows ? http://screenshooter.net/0562655/06_03_2012__09_14_41 and get it like this http://screenshooter.net/0562655/06_03_2012__09_17_38 ? i've try UNION ALL but it doesn't work

Comment: If you use the second solution you will have all in one column plus a extra column indicating if it is at day or at night

Answer (score 0):

At night and at day mean entire day, so just remove HOUR condition

```
SELECT date, SUM(accidents) AS 'at day' FROM vehicles WHERE DATE>='2012-01-01 'AND DATE<='2012-01-31' GRUUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the `WHERE` condition on the HOUR and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT date, 
       IF(HOUR BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '11:59:59','day','night') as period,
       SUM(accidents) as numAccidents
FROM vehicles
WHERE Date >= '2012-01-01' AND DATE <= '2012-01-31'
GROUP BY Date, IF(HOUR BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '11:59:59','day','night')
```

This calculates the 'night' or 'day' using the `IF(condition,then,else)` construct (note depending on the type of your hour column you may have to use `HOUR >= '00:00:00' AND HOUR <= '11:59:59'` instead of `BETWEEN`).

It then groups by both date and day/night to get the aggregate sum per day and period.